# ldapsearch for attribute for non specific OUT at the beginning

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Hello Im facing issues trying to get the attribute of some of my users . Most of them are placed under the same OU "Users" but some of ther are placed on several different OU (INTERNATIONAL USERS or EXTERNAL USERS etc)

Right now Im trying to get the attribute sAMAccountName like this :

```
ldapsearch -u someuser -w somepasword -v -x -H ldap://my.ldap.ip.dir 
-D "CN=MYCN,OU=GENERIC USERS,OU=USERS,DC=set,DC=ads,DC=myorg,DC=ca" 
-b "CN=SAMUEL L JACKSON,OU=DEL,OU=USERS,DC=set,DC=ads,DC=myorg,DC=ca" "(&(objectclass=group)(cn=G LAW *))" 
sAMAccountName
```

But some of the users are not under OU=USERS and I can find them at several locations :

```
ldapsearch -u someuser -w somepasword -v -x -H ldap://my.ldap.ip.dir 
-D "CN=MYCN,OU=GENERIC USERS,OU=USERS,DC=set,DC=ads,DC=myorg,DC=ca" 
-b "CN=SAMUEL L JACKSON,OU=DEL,OU=INTERNATIONAL USERS,DC=set,DC=ads,DC=myorg,DC=ca" "(&(objectclass=group)(cn=G LAW *))" 
sAMAccountName
```

or

```
ldapsearch -u someuser -w somepasword -v -x -H ldap://my.ldap.ip.dir 
-D "CN=MYCN,OU=GENERIC USERS,OU=USERS,DC=set,DC=ads,DC=myorg,DC=ca" 
-b "CN=SAMUEL L JACKSON,OU=DEL,OU=EXTERNAL USERS,DC=set,DC=ads,DC=myorg,DC=ca" "(&(objectclass=group)(cn=G LAW *))" 
sAMAccountName
```

What I would love is to be able to search recursively at -b "CN=SAMUEL L JACKSON,OU=DEL" and get the sAMAccountName at everywhere (maybe they are at INTERNATIONAL USERS or maybe they are at EXTERNAL USERS or at another OU at the same level)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the search base to `DC=set,DC=ads,DC=myorg,DC=ca` (like with FQDN's: reading right to left, keeping the longest part that is common to all matching entries).

Also, the filter is wrong because you don't want group entries starting with specific cn but user entries :

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))
```

If you need only users that are member of a specific group, then you would use :

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(memberOf=<groupDN>))
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, in fact if I do what you say I get all the samaccountnames but I need to filter for a specific user CN=SAMUEL L JACKSON, if there is a specific way to get sammaccount for SAMUEL L JACKSON that would be great:
ldapsearch -u someuser -w somepasword -v -x -H ldap://my.ldap.ip.dir 
-D "CN=MYCN,OU=GENERIC USERS,OU=USERS,DC=set,DC=ads,DC=myorg,DC=ca" 
-b "CN=SAMUEL L JACKSON,OU=DEL,OU=INTERNATIONAL USERS,DC=set,DC=ads,DC=myorg,DC=ca" "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))" sAMAccountName

Comment: Your question was about getting _"the attribute of some of my users"_, you mentioned that "most of them are placed under the same OU [...] but some of the users are not under OU=USERS". My answer is that the base search should be `-b "DC=set,DC=ads,DC=myorg,DC=ca"`.  Now, you can get attributes for specific users by using the proper filter, here given its common name it would be `(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(CN=SAMUEL L JACKSON))`.